# Can I update Minecraft on Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, minecraft-legacy-console

I cannot figure out how to update Minecraft on Xbox 360. It has NEVER been updated in a long time. I have asked friends who have already had the console, but they don't know either. Is Xbox 360 still being updated, or is it deprecated?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they don't update it anymore because it's not a popular console anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft Xbox 360 is a part of the Minecraft Legacy Console series. Legacy Console edition was deprecated in 2017, so it is no longer updated. The only editions that are still updated are Bedrock (PS4, iPad, etc) and Java (PC).

Answer (score 0):

Well, one option would be to try to install the game updates on the pendrive on the PC, and using the Horizon program, move to the updates folder. Or you can jailbreak your xbox 360 using only a USB if it is RGH.

Comment: Please don’t encourage illegal activity.